# Adding Box as a place in Office iOS apps causes SSO login to hang

Tags: single-sign-on, officedev

In some scenarios, users are unable to add Box as a Place in Office iOS apps due to their SSO environment and the lack of support for certain configurations.

For example, where an enterprise has an authentication-challenge-based (HTTP Basic Authentication) SSO - where the user has to be prompted for a username and password outside of the rendered web page.

The user is in an Office iOS app, then attempts to add Box as a Place, expecting to log in to their corporate Box account, and when they get redirected to their SSO environment, they are not presented with a prompt for their username and password.

It just appears to hang. Users should be able to log into their corporate Box account from Office iOS apps without their SSO environment becoming stuck this way.

Comment: What is your question? This is a vague and general description of something that *might* happen in *some scenarios*. If you're looking for a solution, you need to be much clearer about what the problem is, when you encounter it, and what you've already tried to do to solve it.